# Pick 2 lang stream and one video ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, vaapi

Please help me. I have try alot of diffrent code to get this to work, but i can't fix it. So now im going to try to get pro help from you :)

I use this code, it works perfect, but it select all audio stream from eng and swe. How can i get only ony stream of eng and swe audio and one video?

`for f in /mnt/re-encode/*/*.mkv_; do /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -fflags +igndts -analyzeduration 2147483647 -probesize 2147483647 \ -hide_banner -sn -err_detect ignore_err -init_hw_device vaapi=foo:/dev/dri/renderD128 -hwaccel vaapi -hwaccel_output_format vaapi -hwaccel_device foo -i "$f" \ -b:v 6M -minrate 6M -maxrate 6M -bufsize 6M \ -profile:v 100 -level 41 -bf 0 -r film -sn -movflags +faststart+write_colr+prefer_icc \ -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:m:language:eng? -map 0:a:m:language:swe? -filter_hw_device foo -vf "deinterlace_vaapi,scale_vaapi=w=-2:h=720,hwdownload,format=nv12|vaapi,subtitles='${f%.*}.srt',hwupload" -c:v h264_vaapi \ -c:a:0 aac -ac 2 -af "volume=2" -b:a 256k \ -f mp4 -y -hide_banner "${f%.*}_b.mp4_"`

I have tryc pipe: and /dev/null